# Python OOP instances & classes mutability

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I have been doing some readings and thought about this code:

```
def change(c, n: int) -> None:
    c.x = n


class Value:
    x = 5


m = Value()
change(Value, 3)
print(m.x)
change(m, 1)
change(Value, 2)
print(m.x)
```

The output of this code is:

- 3
- 1

So what I assumed is for the 3, m & Value are aliased but changing m's attribute breaks this. I couldn't confirm this by running id() - it turned out m and value always had different ids.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: This prints `3 1`, not `3 2`.

Comment: You mixed class and instace attributes. They behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are changing the value for `Value` you are changing the `x` value shared by all the `value` instances.

When you are changing the value for `m`, you are doing it for `m` and `m` alone, essentially overriding the class `x` with a new *instance* `x`. You can see it with

```
k = Value()
print(k.x) # 2
```